# Why is the regex pattern '?!' not working with grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, history-expansion

One could use `-v` to exclude a single word from a file, but I'm wondering why the regex pattern `?!` is not working with `grep`/`egrep`.

I was searching for a pattern to exclude a single word from my search in a file in `atom` editor and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) link. The `?!` works perfectly in `atom`. In `bash` I had to turn off `histexpand` with `set +H` first, otherwise you get `-bash: !xxx: event not found` as `!pattern` searches the history. After that I tried stuff like `echo "no" | grep "^(?!yes).*"`, but `grep` does somehow not recognize the `?!` pattern - why is that so?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ echo "no" | grep -P '^(?!yes).*'
no
```

The expression is not a standard basic nor standard extended regular expression, but a PCRE, a "Perl compatible regular expression".  GNU `grep` knows about these if you use the utility with its `-P` flag.

Putting the expression in single quotes (which you should do since it's a static string) additionally stops `bash` from recognizing the `?!yes` as a history expansion pattern.

From the GNU `grep` manual:

> `-P`, `--perl-regexp`
>
> Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression
>                 (PCRE).  This is experimental and `grep -P` may warn of
>                 unimplemented features.

From the `bash` manual (my emphasis):

> Only backslash (`\`) **and single quotes** can quote the history
>   expansion character, but the history expansion character is also
>   treated as quoted if it immediately precedes the closing double quote
>   in a double-quoted string.